# Get Values from JSON According to Condition

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a local Json file in app bundle.

Existing Json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "key1": true,
        "key2": "key2Value",
    },
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "key1": false,
        "key2": "key2Value",
    },
    {
        "id": 1003,
        "key1": true,
        "key2": "key2Value",
    },
]
```

I want to loop over the json and get the ids if `key1` value is `true`.

I tried like this but I got error:

```
let vehicleInfoTest: [Vehicle] = readJSONTest("vehicleInfo.json")
func readJSONTest<T: Codable>(_ named: String) -> T{
    let data: Data
    let ids: Int
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("vehicleInfo.json")

        data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        
        // I can successfully get the foo
        let foo = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        
        // For loop gives an error: For-in loop requires 'Vehicle' to conform to 'Sequence'
        for item in foo as! Vehicle{
            if item.key1 == true{
                    ids = item.id
                }
        }
        return foo
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't find  in main bundle.")
    }
}
```

Finally `ids` should be like this:

```
ids = 1001, 1003
```

*How can I get the ids?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit of a mess, you have a generic function that you try to use as a non-generic function and you have also some other messy stuff in it. Since you first need to call the generic function as step 1 and then do the filtering of the result in a second step the following code will give you the Id's where `key1` is true

```
let vehicleInfoTest: [Vehicle] = readJSONTest("vehicleInfo.json")
let idValues = vehicleInfoTest.filter({ $0.key1 }).map( {$0.id })
```

Now to get this to work the function needs to be cleaned up

```
func readJSONTest<T: Codable>(_ named: String) -> T{
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent(named). //use parameter, not hardcoded string

        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) // directly return decoded values
    } catch {
        fatalError("Decoding failed with error \(error)") // More useful error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
let ids = vehicles.filter { $0.key1 }.map { $0.id }
```

instead of your `for` loop should do the trick  - however, this should not be part of the generic method.

Either `readJSONTest` is generic, or it knows about the internals of `Vehicle`, but it really shouldn't do both.

Also, please don't say `x.key1 == true` when key1 is already a non-optional `Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

The non-generic code in the generic function makes no sense.

The loop presumes that `T` is an array **and** the type has a member `key1`. Filter the array outside the loop and make the function `throw`

```
func readJSONTest<T: Decodable>(_ named: String) throws -> T {
    let fileURL = try FileManager.default
        .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("vehicleInfo.json")
    
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    
}
let vehicleInfoTest: [Vehicle] = try readJSONTest("vehicleInfo.json")
let ids = vehicleInfoTest.lazy.filter{$0.key1}.map{$0.id}
```